# Distributive law for adjectives in plural over nouns in singular?

Tags: adjective, article

Maybe the answer is too obvious, but I want to know if it's possible, without ambiguity and fitting still a good style, to substitute, say,

> mit **verletztem Mund** und **verletzter Nase**

by

> mit **verletzten** *Mund* und *Nase*

or

> mit **nassem** *Hemd* und **nassem** *Handtuch*

by

> mit **nassen** *Hemd* und *Handtuch*

---

If so, then consider feminine singular nouns:

> ... **kluge** *Jutta* und *Ela* (both in nominative, without preceding article)

What would you understand from this last one?

1. Only Jutta is smart.
2. Both Jutta and Ela are.
3. You cannot tell, because it's context dependent.
4. The expression is either incorrect or no native speaker wouldn't use it.

Comment: As written in Matthias’ answer, it should be *mit nasse**m** Hemd und Handtuch*

Comment: @Jan Maybe you didn't understand my point: your phrase is grammatically correct, but you can't expect people to understand it the way that _both_ shirt and towel are wet. IMHO most people would understand that only the shirt is said to be wet, so it is not a good substitute for the original phrase.

Comment: @Matthias I didn’t want to imply that that would give an *understandable* sentence, I just wanted to point out that *nasse**n*** would not work at all for being ungrammatical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> mit verletzten Mund und Nase

This doesn't work. Here you are using *verletzt* in plural dative. Since in German adjectives have to [agree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agreement_%28linguistics%29) with their noun on number, case and gender, there must be something in plural that *verletzten* can refer to. *Mund und Nase*, however, do not form a plural entity (at least not to my ears). The same holds true for *Hemd und Handtuch*, so you second example doesn't work either.

There are rare cases where this does work, e.g.

> die berühmten Siegfried und Roy

In this example the names of the two artists appear like the name of a group that can be used like a plural word.

> mit verletzte**m** Mund und Nase

as it was suggested in another answer, *might* work – but only because "mit Nase" alone doesn't seem to make sense at all, so that a reader might accept the error in agreement (*Nase* is feminine, while *verletztem* is masculine) in exchange for more reason. But the error still lingers around, making this phrase sound wrong somehow. Compare

> mit gebrochener Nase und Sonnenbrille

Nobody would think of broken sun glasses here, even though agreement rules would be obeyed. And that's not only because one would use "zerbrochen", not "gebrochen" for glasses.

Another example:

> Ich esse gerne frischen Fisch und Käse.

Again, *frisch* is only applied to *Fisch* – *Käse* stands on its own and is not described in detail.

And finally:

> kluge Jutta und Ela

It's similar to the *Fisch/Käse* example, so I'd say it's option 1) – and 4), because I cannot figure how someone would use it without an article. But maybe someone might come up with a context where this phrase, without article, does sound natural and can be understood in the way of 2), so you could also say it is 3) ;-)

Answer (score 7):

In both cases I would tend to avoid the proposed phrases. For the first example:

> mit Verletzungen an Mund und Nase

sounds somewhat better.

> mit verletztem Mund und Nase

would also be viable in my opinion, since the mere existence of a nose is unquestionable and occuring in this sentence clearly indicates it also to be covered by *verletztem*.

The second example is therefore more ambiguous, since Ela may be simply mentioned or also categorized as *klug*, so I tend to (3). To resolve ambiguity one could use something like

> die klugen Frauen Jutta und Ela.